# Não entendo o erro None nessa função

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Não consigo entender porque no fim essa função não retorna uma string. O erro fica em `fptr.write(result + '\n')`, como se a função retornasse um objeto do tipo `None`.

```
def dnaComplement(s):
    complement = []
    complement0 = reversed(s)
    for character in complement0:
        if character == 'G':
            complement.append('C')
        elif character == 'C':
            complement.append('G')
        elif character == 'A':
            complement.append('T')
        elif character == 'T':
            complement.append('A')
    final = ''.join(complement)
    print(final)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    s = input()

    result = str(dnaComplement(s))

    fptr.write(result + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou a função retornar um valor. No final deveria ter um `return final`:

```
def dnaComplement(s):
    complement = []
    complement0 = reversed(s)
    for character in complement0:
        if character == 'G':
            complement.append('C')
        elif character == 'C':
            complement.append('G')
        elif character == 'A':
            complement.append('T')
        elif character == 'T':
            complement.append('A')
    final = ''.join(complement)
    print(final)
    return final # <-- aqui
```

Quando não há nenhum `return`, a função retorna `None`**¹** (veja mais detalhes na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)). Colocando um valor de retorno, ela se comporta como você espera, retornando a string.

---

Ou ainda, se não quiser imprimir e não for usar a variável `final` para mais nada, nem precisa dela, pode retornar direto o resultado do `join`:

```
def dnaComplement(s):
    complement = []
    complement0 = reversed(s)
    for character in complement0:
        if character == 'G':
            complement.append('C')
        elif character == 'C':
            complement.append('G')
        elif character == 'A':
            complement.append('T')
        elif character == 'T':
            complement.append('A')
    return ''.join(complement)
```

E como o retorno de [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) já é uma string, não precisa usar `str(dnaComplement(s))`, basta chamar a função diretamente que você já terá uma string:

```
s = input()
result = dnaComplement(s) # retorno da função é uma string, não precisa de str()
# etc...
```

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas você pode simplificar a função usando um dicionário contendo os mapeamentos entre os caracteres:

```
def dnaComplement(s):
    comps = { 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G', 'A': 'T', 'T': 'A' }
    complement = []
    for character in reversed(s):
        complement.append(comps[character])
    return ''.join(complement)
```

E pode ainda usar uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052)), aí nem precisa gerar a lista `complement`:

```
def dnaComplement(s):
    comps = { 'G': 'C', 'C': 'G', 'A': 'T', 'T': 'A' }
    return ''.join(comps[character] for character in reversed(s))
```

---

**1**: a exceção a esta regra é quando a função tem um `yield` em vez de `return`, [aí ela se torna um *generator*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

Answer (score 0):

assim como o amigo falou aí em cima, você precisa retornar uma função.

outra maneira "forçar a string" com : `return ''.join(complement)`

vc pode retornar somente:`return str(complement)`